# Why do we have this equality regarding subgroup indices?

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory

Let $H_1, H_2$ be groups (can be non commutative), let $K$ be a subgroup of $H_1 \times H_2$. Let us denote $p$ the projection from $H_1 \times H_2$ to $H_1$ defined by $p(x, y) = x$ and let $L = \lbrace x \in H_2 \vert (e, x) \in K \rbrace$ ($e$ is the neutral element of $H_1$). I have read that we have the following equality:
$$[H_1 \times H_2: K] = [H_1 : p(K)] [H_2 : L]$$
Could anyone please help me understand why this is true? I have already tried some naive ideas which failed.
If necessary we may suppose that $[H_1 \times H_2: K]$ is finite but I do not think this is necessary.

Comment: Hint: find an exact sequence $1\rightarrow H_2/L \rightarrow (H_1\times H_2)/K\rightarrow H_2/p(K)\rightarrow 1$. The question would be more appropriate at MSE.

Comment: What kind of morphism would you use for speaking of exact sequences? Because here the quotients are not groups since nothing guaranties that $K$ is a normal subgroup. How can I move this question to MSE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** I have a favorite hammer, which is Goursat's Lemma, which describes subgroups of $H_1\times H_2$ in terms of certain "graphs" of isomorphisms of groups $A/N$ with $A\leq H_1$ and groups $B/M$ with $B\leq H_2$. It lurks behind the calculations below, which may very well be more complicated than necessary. I do not assume finiteness.  An explanation of the intuition is at the end.

Let $q$ be the projection onto the second component. Note that $K\leq p(K)\times q(K)$, so we have
$$\begin{align*}
[H_1\times H_2:K] &= [H_1\times H_2:p(K)\times q(K)][p(K)\times q(K):K]\\
 &= [H_1:p(K)][H_2:q(K)][p(K)\times q(K):K].\\
\end{align*}$$
So the equality will follow if we have
$$[H_2:q(K)][p(K)\times q(K):K] = [H_2:L].\tag{1}$$
Because $L\leq q(K)$, we have
$$[H_2:L] = [H_2:q(K)][q(K):L]$$
so $(1)$ will follow if we have
$$[p(K)\times q(K):K] = [q(K):L]\tag{2}$$

So we may assume that $K$ is subdirect product (so that $p(K)=H_1$, $q(K)=H_2$), and we want to prove that in that situation,
$$[H_1\times H_2:K] = [H_2:L].$$

Define $\phi$ from the cosets of $L$ in $H_2$ to the cosets of $K$ in $H_1\times H_2$ as follows: given $b\in H_2$, there exists $a\in H_1$ such that $(a,b)\in K$. Map $bL$ to $(a,e)K$.

First:  if $(a',b),(a,b)\in K$, then $(a'^{-1}a,b^{-1}b) = (a'^{-1}a,e)\in K$, so $(a,e)K = (a',e)K$; thus, $\phi$ does not depend on the choice of $a$.

Second: we prove well-defined and one-to-one together. Let $b,b'\in H_2$, and let $a,a'\in H_1$ be such that $(a,b),(a',b')\in K$.  Then
$$\begin{align*}
bL=b'L &\iff b^{-1}b'\in L\\
&\iff (e,b^{-1}b')\in K\\
&\iff (a',b')^{-1}(a,b)(e,b^{-1}b')\in K\\
&\iff (a'^{-1}a,e)\in K\\
&\iff (a',e)K = (a,e)K\\
&\iff \phi(bL) = \phi(b'L).
\end{align*}$$

Finally: $\phi$ is surjective: given $(a,b)\in H_1\times H_2$, there exists $x\in H_1$ such that $(x,b)\in K$. And there exists $b'\in H_2$ such that $(ax^{-1},b')\in K$. Then $\phi(b'L) = (ax^{-1},e)K$. But $(ax^{-1},e)^{-1}(a,b) = (x,b)\in K$, so $(a,b)K = (ax^{-1},e)K = \phi(b'L)$. Thus, $\phi$ is surjective.

Hence $\phi$ is a bijection, showing that $[H_2:L]=[H_1\times H_2:K]$, as desired.

---

**Explanation.** For a subgroup $K$ of $H_1\times H_2$ such that $\pi_1(K)=H_1$ and $\pi_2(K)=H_2$, if we let $M$ be the subgroup of $H_1$ such that $M\times\{e\}=\ker(\pi_2)\cap K$ and let $L$ be the subgroup of $H_2$ such that $\{e\}\times L=\ker(\pi_1)\cap K$, then the function $f\colon H_1/M \to H_2/L$ given by $f(aM) = bN$ if and only if $(a,b)\in K$ is an isomorphism. In this situation, $[H_1\times H_2:K] = [(H_1/M)\times (H_2/L):K/(M\times L)]$. But now $K/(M\times L)$ is the graph of an isomorphism from $H_1/M$ to $H_2/L$, so the index is just $|H_1/M|=|H_2/L| = [H_2:L]$. So this gives $[H_1\times H_2:K] = [H_2:L]=[H_1:M]$. The bijection $\phi$ defined above is based on this isomorphism, as it corresponds to the idea that the element $bL$ maps to the element $aM$ when $(a,b)\in K$.

That is the computation above. The additional factor of $[H_1:\pi_1(K)]$ is there to account for the situation where $K$ is not a subdirect product.

Comment: Thank you! This fully answers my question. Indeed I was struggling to find a bijection but reducing our problem to a subdirect product helps a lot as I can see.

Answer (score 2):

The kernel of the epimorphism $K\to p(K)$ is $\{e\}\times L$, so $p(K)$ is isomorphic to $K/(\{e\}\times L)$, and the equality follows.

Comment: I agree with your statement but I am not sure why this yields the equality could you please enlighten me?

Comment: Well, I assumed that $H_1$ and $H_2$ are finite groups. So things follow just from looking at group orders, as your equality is equivalent to $|p(K)|=|K|/|L|$.

Comment: I see, thank you for you answer but unfortunately I need this for groups that are not necessarily finite. To be more precise I would need this for $H_1 = H_2 = SL_2(\mathbb{R})$.